# f(x) is a non negative function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

> Let $f(x)$be a non-negative function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\le 2f(x)$ for all $x>0$. Then, on $[0,∞)$,
>
> A. $f(x)$ is always a constant function
>
> B. $f(x)$ is strictly increasing
>
> C. $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing
>
> C. $f'(x)$ changes sign

---

My attempt

- multiply by $e^{-2x}$
  so by solving the diff we get $0≤f(x)≤ce^{2x}$
  where $c$ is a positive constant
- therefore none of the options above match
- but the answer given is $f(x)$ is a constant function
- the given answer could have been correct only if it was given $f(x)$ is negative
- but f(x) is given to be non negative

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have gone one step further and determined the constant $c$ as $f(0)$ which is $0$ so that indeed you find the constant zero function as the only possible solution.
\begin{align}
&(e^{-2x}f(x))'=e^{-2x}(f'(x)-2f(x))\le0
\\\implies& 
\int_0^x(e^{-2s}f(s))'\,ds=e^{-2x}f(x)- e^{-2·0}f(0)\le0
\\\implies& 
f(x)\le f(0)\,e^{2x}=0\qquad\text{(per $f(0)=0$)}
\end{align}

See Gronwall lemma, but your idea using the integrating factor is equivalent to it in this case.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in my op.IT WAS e^2X PLEASE CHECK NOW

Comment: @MathMan: It does not change the fact that the upper bound is zero times a positive number. Look at the source code of correct formulas via edit or the context menu to find ways to improve your formulas.`e^{2x}`

Comment: I have a small problem with ur answer.

Comment: instead of expanding if we directly take $(e^{-2x}*f(x))<=0$

Comment: and integrate it wont u get the above inequality that i wrote where f(x) can be increasing as well

Comment: If you do not want to finish that early, then you get $0\le f(x)\le f(0)e^{2x}$. If $f(0)$ were positive, then yes, $f(x)$ could be increasing. As $f(0)=0$ per task, this is not possible.

Comment: can u tell how does one get that f(x)<=f(0)e^{-2x} ?

Comment: By multiplying the formula after integration of $(e^{-2x}f(x))'\le0$  from $0$ to $x$ with $e^{2x}$, omitting the $=0$ part.

Comment: SORRY BUT I AM not able to ndedrstand what u have done but anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach: division by $ f $ shows $(\log f (x))'\leq 2$ and thus $ f (x)\leq f (0) \exp 2x$.

Since $ f (x)=0$ you are not allowed to divide by $ f $. To fix this apply the argument to $ f_{\epsilon}=f+\epsilon $